# Mirroring a website with wget based on specific query-string

Tags: unix, wget

I'm trying to mirror a website with the following URL format:

http://example.com/homepage?page=1

I want to mirror only the ones using the query string from page=1 to page=100. How do I do this as efficient as possible with wget?

I do not need to mirror recursively, only pages 1 to 100. Saving the CSS/JS will also be nice. Excluding images can be great too to keep it fast (only interested in the text).

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a list of URLs:

```
seq 1 100 | xargs -n 1 -I {} echo http://example.com/homepage?page={} > URLS.txt
```

Then download all with wget:

```
wget -i URLS.txt
```